# Inscrease bullet points spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, bullets

I have a table which I did for my MSc thesis, that worked just fine:
[image: correct table]

However, now I want to use that table for an article. I have copied the code, but the bullet points from the 2nd column are too close (vertically):
[image: Table where bullets are too close]

Any idea how I can fix this? I have tried some things suggested at StackExchange, but none of them worked.
This is the code for a test document (where the problem does NOT stand):

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{article}

%Import packages
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{{#1}}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs,eqparbox,tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Implemented methods, and corresponding computed metrics.}
    \label{table:computed_metrics}
    \small
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
        leftmargin=*,
        before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\RaggedLeft}p{3.6cm} p{4.2cm} p{5.8cm}}
        \hline
        \textbf{Method name}            & \textbf{Metrics}                       & \textbf{Method explanation}                                                                                                                                                                               \\ \hline
        \textbf{Simple statistical metrics} & \begin{itemize}
            \item Mean
            \item Standard deviation (SD)
        \end{itemize}                                   & Computes the mean value and the amount of variation (SD) of a feature's time-series.                                                                                                        \\
        \textbf{Linear variability}              & \begin{itemize}
            \item  Slope of regression ($\alpha$)
            \item Median variability ($m$)
        \end{itemize}                                                 & Calculates the variability of a feature's time-series, and studies how that variability progresses with time (increases [$\alpha>0$], decreases [$\alpha<0$] or maintains [$\alpha=0$]). \\
        \textbf{Non-linear variability}          & \begin{itemize}
            \item Central tendency measurement (CTM)
        \end{itemize}     & Computes the feature's time-series variability using difference plots. The higher the CTM, the lower the variability, and vice-versa.                                                                                                  \\
        \textbf{P-wave amplitude dispersion}          & \begin{itemize}
            \item Amplitude dispersion index (ADI)
        \end{itemize}     & Quantitative indicator of P-wave morphology variability. The greater the ADI, the greater the variability, and vice-versa. Uses the P-waves' signal.                                                                                        \\
        \textbf{Heart rate variability}          & \begin{itemize}
            \item \textoverline{RR}, SDRR, SDSD, RMSSD, NN20, pNN20, NN50, pNN50 
            \item TP, VLF, LF, HF, pHF, pLF, LF/HF
        \end{itemize}
        & Studies the variability of the RR series using metrics from time- and frequency- domain. Gives indications on the autonomic nervous system.                                            \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

I can't provide a full compilable code, given that I'm using a template from the Sensors Journal (https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex). However, you can download my full compilable code here: https://ufile.io/n7pg8

Many thanks!
Diogo

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: you should provide a MWE, a small complete document, which reproduce your problem. Link can become after while dead and  will be not possible to know, what is actually your problem.

Comment: Hello all. As I mentioned, I cannot provide a full compilable code, given that the template contains files other than the main code. I have tried to reproduce the problem in another clean document, but the table got different. Nonetheless I will provide that document, but I warn that the output is different.

Comment: i copy your table code in my test environment and i can't reproduce your problem. for MWE: to your code fragment you only need to add `\documenclas{...}˙and necessary part of preamble, which will enable to test your code as it is.

Comment: Well, same for me. It works perfectly for me on a black document, which probably means it is something from the template (that I can't change). Do you still want me to provide the test environment, even though the problem is not present there?

Comment: yes, w need at least your `\documentclass` and used document preamble (a part which reproduce your problem).

Comment: Done. Can you please check it? Probably you'll have to check the download link. I have also provided info about the template, so that we can generalize the answer to other users of the template.

Comment: i test your MWE. It works as expected: it not reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko, I have already mentioned that several times. I cannot reproduce my problem on a MWE, because the problem only occurs using the template. I have generalised the questions by providing a link to the template (the link will last forever) and mentioning the Journal.

Comment: there is no general reason for your problem. apparently your "template" (`\documentclass`) overwrite `\itemize` settings. since your original `\documentclass` is not known to us, we can't help you. sorry.

Comment: Can't you please download the template document and check what's the problem? or suggest a workaround

Comment: @DiogoTec mdpi.cls consists of more than 1170 lines of code. Please turn to the helpdesk of mdpi.com, they even offer an emailaddress.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{Definitions/mdpi}
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}$} % simplified
%
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\caption{Implemented methods, and corresponding computed metrics.}
\label{table:computed_metrics}
\small
\setlist[itemize]{ % nosep,         % <--- remove "nosep"
                    leftmargin=*,
                    before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                    after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                }
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=0.6\hsize\bfseries}L L
                             >{\hsize=1.4\hsize}L
                             }
    \toprule
Method name &   \thead{Metrics}    &   \thead{Method explanation}         \\
    \midrule
Simple statistical metrics
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Mean
    \item Standard deviation (SD)
        \end{itemize}
        &  Computes the mean value and the amount of variation (SD) of a feature's time-series.
        \\
Linear variability
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item  Slope of regression ($\alpha$)
    \item Median variability ($m$)
        \end{itemize}
        & Calculates the variability of a feature's time-series, and studies how that variability progresses with time (increases [$\alpha>0$], decreases [$\alpha<0$] or maintains [$\alpha=0$]).
        \\
Non-linear variability
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Central tendency measurement (CTM)
        \end{itemize}
        & Computes the feature's time-series variability using difference plots. The higher the CTM, the lower the variability, and vice-versa.
        \\
P-wave amplitude dispersion
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item Amplitude dispersion index (ADI)
        \end{itemize}
        & Quantitative indicator of P-wave morphology variability. The greater the ADI, the greater the variability, and vice-versa. Uses the P-waves' signal.
        \\
Heart rate variability
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item \textoverline{RR}, SDRR, SDSD, RMSSD, NN20, pNN20, NN50, pNN50
    \item TP, VLF, LF, HF, pHF, pLF, LF/HF
        \end{itemize}
        & Studies the variability of the RR series using metrics from time- and frequency- domain. Gives indications on the autonomic nervous system.                                            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

result tested on overleaf gives the following result:

[image]

In MWE above i made some off-topic changes which (according to my taste) made table more nice (use of `tabularx` for table environment, `makecell` for more vertical space above and below cell contents).

**Addendum:**
Apparently document class `mdpi` has hard coded `itemize` list, which can be overwritten with use of the `enumitem` package. Also it seems, when `itemize` is used in table, the `\parsep` and `\itemsep` are reduced.

One way for increasing of the vertical space between items is adding `\\[1.5ex]` after end of each item. Using this solution, you not need `enumetem` package anymore. So the lists in table you can write as in MWE above, or you can define new column type as is done in MWE below:

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{Definitions/mdpi}
\newcommand*{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\hbox{#1}}$} % simplified
%
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{I}{>{\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{1em}
    \itemize%
           }L<{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\enditemize\endminipage}%
                }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Mean
    \item Standard deviation (SD)
\end{itemize}
    \begin{table}[h]
\caption{Implemented methods, and corresponding computed metrics.}
\label{table:computed_metrics}
\small
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=0.7\hsize\bfseries}L
                             I%{\textbullet}
                             >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}L
                             }
    \toprule
Method name 
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Metrics}}    
                &   \thead{Method explanation}         
        \\
    \midrule
Simple statistical metrics
    &   \item Mean\\[1.5ex]
        \item Standard deviation (SD)
        &  Computes the mean value and the amount of variation (SD) of a feature's time-series.
        \\
Linear variability
    &   \item  Slope of regression ($\alpha$)\\[.51ex]
        \item Median variability ($m$)
        & Calculates the variability of a feature's time-series, and studies how that variability progresses with time (increases [$\alpha>0$], decreases [$\alpha<0$] or maintains [$\alpha=0$]).
        \\
Non-linear variability
    &   \item Central tendency measurement (CTM)
        & Computes the feature's time-series variability using difference plots. The higher the CTM, the lower the variability, and vice-versa.
        \\
P-wave amplitude dispersion
    &   \item Amplitude dispersion index (ADI)
        & Quantitative indicator of P-wave morphology variability. The greater the ADI, the greater the variability, and vice-versa. Uses the P-waves' signal.
        \\
Heart rate variability
    &   \item \textoverline{RR}, SDRR, SDSD, RMSSD, NN20, pNN20, NN50, pNN50\\[1.5ex]
        \item TP, VLF, LF, HF, pHF, pLF, LF/HF
        & Studies the variability of the RR series using metrics from time- and frequency- domain. Gives indications on the autonomic nervous system.                                            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: The first item in the list seems to start lower than the first line of the text in the first and third column. Maybe you could use `before=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}`. (I have not tested this since I did not have access to the documentclass used in the question.)

Comment: Hello! Many thanks for your help :) I did work! Is there any way to increase the spacing between the two bullets? That'd be great!

Comment: @DiogoTec: You could add the `itemsep=<length>` option (with a <length> of your choice) to the ` \setlist[itemize]` command.

Comment: @leandriis many thanks. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've tried several lenghts (1cm to 20cm) and they produce no changes

Comment: @DiogoTec: I can not reproduce this. If I use the MWE ftrom Zarko's answer and add `itemsep=1cm` to `\setlist[itemize]` I obtain the following result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5giML.png